# Is there a concise book on how math and measurements are used in Torah and talmud?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, shiurim-measurements

Both the Torah and Gemarrah use math in various places, e.g. percentages (5ths (certain penalties); 10ths (*ma'aser*), etc.)

They also use many terms of measurements - e.g. shekel = 20 gerah; numerous measurements (efah, e.g.) for sacrifices, etc.

Is there a book that explains in brief terms what these measurements are, with translations to either U.S. or metric terms, as well as cross refs. to either verses or Talmud page, etc. where these terms are mentioned?

Hard-copy book preferred, but a web site will also suffice.

Comment: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA,_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94

Answer (score 4):

If I recall correctly, Aryeh Carmell's  [*Aiding Talmud Study* (Siyata LeGemara)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0873064283) has a few pages on Talmudic units of measurement.

Comment: +1, it does, and it's a great resource, though incomplete. (E.g., IIRC, it doesn't include the _chomer_ unit of volume, and it makes no mention when translating to modern measures of whether it's using desert, Jerusalem, or Sepphoris volumes.)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t cross-reference to actual cases, but [shteinzalt’s Madrich LeTalmud](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A_%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93) has charts showing the relationships between many types of measurements as well as money.